# Routing with an optional parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-2

I added in the route file:

```
map.show_book "/show_book/:name/year/:year", :controller => "book", :action => "show_version"
```

I also added:

```
map.show_book "/show_book/:name", :controller => "book", :action => "show_version"
```

to show the latest book without specifying the year.

But it doesn't work, it cannot find the route in "show_book/NAME" if I don't pass the year.

Do you have some ideas why it doesn't work ?

THANKS !

PS.
I know that I can use year as parameter with "?year=XXXX", but I want to use the year as a part of the URL

Answer (score 134, accepted):

[Put the optional parts between parenthesis](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters):

```
map.show_book "/show_book/:name(/year/:year)", :controller => "book", :action => "show_version"
```

and remove the second route.

**Update**

The above answer is only for rails 3 and above. Inverting the two routes definitions fixed the problem (see Alessandro's comment below).

Comment: Wow, this it is very simple, but I think it is only for Rails3. I forgot to specify that the project is in rails 2.3. But I have find out that it's enough to use both routes, but in a correct order (I wrote it in a wrong order).
Thanks

Comment: "Only" is no longer true, since this is valid in Rails 4, and likely future versions as well.

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple optional parts in the same route with an unspecified order?  Soa long the lines of...

map.show_book "/show_book/:name((/year/:year)(/day/:day))"

Comment: @EricWalsh you should ask that as a question, you're much more likely to get an answer (haven't touched rails for a long time, I won't be of much use)

Comment: Thanks @BenoitGarret, I opened up a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501364/rails-3-route-with-multiple-optional-parameters) just wanted to see if anyone in the thread would be able to shed some light!

Comment: How to make attachments `:id` optional in a route like this: `PATCH  /pages/:page_id/attachments/:id(.:format)  attachments#update` defined by `resources :pages do
  resources :attachments, only: [:create, :destroy, :update]
 end
`

Comment: Damn, been using Rails for over a decade and this is the first time I've seen this. F'ing magical.