# What is the best way to declare optional named path parameters in Apache Wink

Tags: java, rest, web, apache-wink

What is the best way to define optional named parameters in a REST path using [Apache Wink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wink)?

Right now I am using something like this:

```
/items{sep: (?)}{id: (.*)}")
```

for matching requests such as:

```
/items/123
/items/
/items
```

so that I can capture a clean `{id}`.

Another option would be:

```
/items{id: (/?/[^/]+?)}
```

but then the `{id}` will contain the `/` character and it will require a cleanup.

I am using Wink in my framework [(µ)Micro](https://github.com/florinpatrascu/micro) and I am planning to stick with it, recommending other/better(?) similar frameworks would not answer this question at this time.

Thank you!
-florin

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit cumbersome, dunno, maybe this isn't a better solution than yours (I don't know your requirements) but here's how I did it. My resource class has an annotation of '@Path("/db")', and then successive methods for each supported directory level, i.e., since REST is based on URLs that will necessarily treat '/' characters as directory delimiters.

```
@Path("{id}")
@GET
public Response getJson( @PathParam("id") String id )
{  
    String path = id;
    // TODO
}
```

handles "db/items", and

```
@Path("{id1}/{id2}")
@GET
public Response getJson( 
        @PathParam("id1") String id,
        @PathParam("id2") String id2 )
{
    String path = id1 + '/' + id2;
    // TODO
}
```

handles "db/items/123", and

```
@Path("{id1}/{id2}/{id3}")
@GET
public Response getJson( 
        @PathParam("id1") String id1, 
        @PathParam("id2") String id2, 
        @PathParam("id3") String id3 )
{ 
    String path = id1 + '/' + id2 + '/' + id3;
    // TODO
}
```

handles "db/items/123/456".

But you can see this quickly becomes cumbersome on longer paths, and I haven't yet figured out how to handle n-depth paths (*anyone?*). Hope that's of some help.

Comment: Thank you, Ichiro. I am really interested to see if Wink can accomodate optional path parameters. I know how to do it with Rails, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281592/routing-with-an-optional-parameter) is a good example and I thought I can use a similar syntax with Wink. I [solved my problem](https://github.com/florinpatrascu/micro-examples/blob/master/todos/WEB-INF/config/routes.yml#L13) using regexp though I am still hoping there is a cleaner way. I'll keep the question open for now. Thanks again!